# ACH credit from unknown source

Tags: ach

So I received an ACH credit of about $100 in my Chase current account from a source I do not recognize. The transaction description includes "REGMANGR1 6873 CCD+"

I called Chase, and the rep told me the transaction is from my small company with an account an Bank of America. My small company exists, but I have never had a business account through it at BOA, and I know for sure I have never processed any payment through it.

The whole situation seems quite suspicious. What do I do? I suspect criminals are up to something with my account number

Comment: By "_the transaction is from **my** small company_" and "_**My** small company exists_" do you really mean you **own** the small company that sent the payment? Or should it be "_from **a** small company_" and "_**The** small company exists_" (but you have never dealt with them)?

Comment: I own the small company that is supposedly the sender (or recipient, I'm not sure) of the payment, but my small company has no business account (its basically a sole proprietorship), and I have absolutely no recollection of having sent any such payment myself. The rep told me it is supposedly a refund; for what, I have no idea

Comment: So a BoA account you know nothing of was seemingly opened in the name of a company you own, and then sent your main account $100? I think you're right to be suspicious, but I can't see a downside at the moment, since you seem to be up $100 (but I guess that's how all the best scams work: you don't see the downside until too late).

Comment: I don't have a definite answer, but I would suggest reaching out to BoA also to see if you can hunt down more information about the transaction. I've heard of banking errors where money gets mistakenly deposited to accounts (and later retracted), but the fact that it comes from "your company" makes this a bit more suspicious.

Comment: I know that you already figured out the source, and the $100 amount means it's probably not a trial deposit, but if anyone has unexplained deposits and finds this question, I think my answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

OK, I just called BoA; apparently the payment was a refund from an office space company called Regus, where I had an office in my company's name before. It seems this was refund of my security deposit. I feel much better now since this seems to be a legitimate transaction. Thanks for your responses

Answer (score 0):

Unexplained deposits could be trial deposits from attempting to link your bank account with another account. If you were to link a BoA account to a Chase account, BoA would make a couple deposits (usually less than a dollar) into the Chase account. These would show up as "BANK OF AMERICA TRIAL DEP", or something similar. In order convince BoA that your really own the Chase account, you need to confirm the value of those deposits.

So what should you do if you suspect criminals have your account number? Change the passwords for your bank account and your email account and notify your bank immediately. If someone can link to your account they will be able to draw funds from your account. If someone got your account number they can try to link it to your bank account. Then they need to log into your account to find the value of the trial deposits, which they can do if they have your online banking password. If they have access to your email account, they can use it to reset your online banking password. If there's any chance that your password was compromised, or your email password was compromised, change them. Change them even if you think there's no chance they were compromised. If you used the same password for other banks or websites, change those too.

It's unlikely this is a trial deposit because there's only one, and it's so large. But if you think someone is up to something suspicious with your accounts, changing your passwords is cheap insurance. That should be the first step if something suspicious like this happens.

Comment: OP answered his own question 11 hours ago.

Comment: @RonJohn I know, and I acknowledged that in a comment after I wrote this answer. I think this answer is general and can be helpful to other people with a similar question.